# Twilio - SMS mask my twilio number (from) with a non-twilio number

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have some 1-800 numbers - not hosted on Twilio - that I want to use as the "from" number for an sms app I am building using Twilio.  Is there a way to mask the Twilio number with one of these non-Twilio numbers so that the text message appears to be coming from the non-twilio number?

Example:

1. My app sends text to customer using the Twilio number as the "from" number.
2. Twilio masks the Twilio number so that it appears that the text came from the 1-800 number.
3. Customer can respond via text and it will route back through twilio and not try to send a text to the 1-800 number.
4. If customer tries calling the number back, it will NOT route back through Twilio, but actually call the 1-800 number.

FYI - the 1-800 numbers are VoIP numbers and therefore cannot use the new hosted sms functionality built into Twilio.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed Toll Free numbers (VoIP) [hosted numbers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/hosted-numbers) on Twilio, VoIP numbers are supported. Open a support ticket with Twilio about hosting these numbers.

You cannot use non-Twilio numbers as the From for outbound SMS. [Verified CallerID](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180048-Adding-a-Verified-Phone-Number-or-Caller-ID-with-Twilio) only works for Voice calls, not SMS.

Comment: "If you would like to check the eligibility before submitting the phone number, Twilio offers Lookup, a tool to see information about the number. If a number is not of type VoIP or mobile, then the number is eligible to be Hosted for SMS."  This is directly from the hosted numbers documentation.  It appears that VoIP numbers are NOT supported.  Are you saying that they will support it if I open up a ticket with them?

Comment: Yes, for most VoiP providers it is supported. Some VoIP providers will not release the SPID so customer using those providers cannot host their SMS on another carrier. Support will be able to determine this.